# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s + r_2 + r_3}$

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

I have the Laplace transform of $x$ as follows:

$$
x_L=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s + r_2 + r_3},
$$

where $x$ is a function of $t$, and $x_L$ is a function of $s$.

I know the inverse Laplace transform of

$$
\frac{e^{-cs}}{s}
$$

is

$$
H(t-c),
$$

but I'm not sure how to deal with the $r_y$ factors in my equation for $x_L$.

What is the inverse Laplace transform of $x_L$ as defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$
x_L=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s + r_2 + r_3}
$$

can be split into

$$
x_L=r_1e^{-t_0s}\frac{1}{s + r_2 + r_3}.
$$

Define $f_L=\frac{1}{s + r_2 + r_3}$.

According to my table of commonly encountered Laplace transforms, I have

$$
H(t-c)f(t-c)=e^{-cs}f_L(s).
$$

Hence, at this point, in order to solve the overall problem, I just need to know how to compute the inverse Laplace transform of my $f_L$ to get $f(t)$.

Another entry in my table is

$$
e^{at}=\frac{1}{s-a}, s>a.
$$

If we define $a=-r_2-r_3$, we have

$$
e^{(-r_2-r_3)t}=f(t).
$$

Defining $c=t_0$, we can solve the overall problem:

\begin{align}
x&=r_1[H(t-t_0)f(t-c)]\\
x&=r_1\bigg[H(t-t_0)e^{(-r_2-r_3)(t-t_0)}\bigg].
\end{align}